# What happens to my data post-installation?

Tags: installation

I want to download ubuntu in place of Windows 8. I am just curious as to what happens to my saved data upon installation of ubuntu. Will my files be present after installation?

Answer (score 1):

When you go in for installing Ubuntu (applies to all the versions), you have 3 options that may be considered

**1.Install Alongside Windows**

Here, the bootloader reads your disks, checks for other OSes and basically displays what you can install Ubuntu with. In this case, all your data is **preserved** and you will not lose any saved data.

**2.Remove Everything and install Ubuntu**

In this case you will **lose all your data**. Everything, the LiveUSB shall format all your drives and you will have a machine with Ubuntu only. Your data that is linked with Windows will be formated

**3.Something Else**

Here, you have an option of how much space you want to allocate, to which disk, swap space, everything. Total customization is available via this option. Now in this option you **may or may not lose data**. It depends on how you choose to create your new partitions really.

So this is how these options work. Hope you have a successful installation!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu over windows completely overriding the windows files. If you do this, backup everything before the install. Or you could install it alongside Windows and it will give an option to partition your HDD so you can use both. This will leave you with access to your files.